# Dark colors in SwiftUi Mac

Tags: swiftui

Starting a new Mac App project from scratch and assigning `Color.red` and `Color.green` to two `Rectangle`s results in the following:

[image]

Code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                .background(Color.green)

           Spacer()

            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                .background(Color.red)
        }
    }
}

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Where do those very dark colors come from? How to have the interface use "normal" colors? I don't have dark mode activated and I'm on Big Sur.

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @pawello2222 Done, but it's really just that. Using Color.red or Color.green results in a super dark red or green.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `fill` or `foregroundColor` instead of `background`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.green) // first possibility: `fill`
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)

            Spacer()

            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color.red) // second possibility: `foregroundColor`
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's correct. To fill a shape use `.fill(Color.green)`.